# Maven JBOSS application deployment

Tags: maven, jboss

I followed this tutorial http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-maven/jboss-maven-example-building-a-java-ee-6-application/ in order to have a simple web application to better understand Java EE and JBOSS. I set up the example project (by archetype) and compiled it.

However, I am stuck after running mvn compile. I want to deploy my application as a war file to my JBOSS webroot directory (in my case /usr/share/jboss-as/standalone/deployments/).

I think mvn package and mvn install must be executed. Where can I specify that I want a war file and that it should be copied to my deployment location on JBOSS?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I can use the jboss maven plugin http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/, which is addressed via console

```
jboss-as:deploy
```

Configuration is read from the POM file.

Comment: That line was missing from the article. Thanks a lot for pointing it out, I've corrected it. Best regards

Comment: Is there a way to determine the servers name and port (as pointed out in the custom configuration in this article http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-maven/maven-jboss-as-7-plugin-tutorial). I can access my installation via web console at http://devel:9990. That does not work for the maven configuration. I suppose name and password can be the management realm users?

Comment: Yes username and password are management realm users created with add-user script, however there is no way to access server name and port without prior connecting to the server.

Comment: Accessing the server is not a problem, but how can I determine what must be entered as server name and port?

Comment: Eventualy, got it working. Had to update to JBOSS EAP 6.1.Alpha with maven plugin version 7.5.